# 60/70's sci fi story about a male teenager with telekinesis

Tags: story-identification, telekinesis

I remember reading an old sci fi story (probably 60's/70's) about a male teenager who discovers he has some sort of telekinetic power after a botched date with a girl at his school. I believe he wishes to go inside her place and make out but she declines. As he leaves her doorstep, he looks back at her furiously and 'mentally' pushes her.

He then goes on to discover and hone his power, figuring it must be due to the fact that he's a virgin.

At school, the girl questions him about it and knows that he's 'different' and becomes enticed by him. They wind up having sex and the main character mourns the loss of his power.

Answer (score 7):

That's [Robert Silverberg's](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?54) [*Push No More*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58628).

A description from his [semi-official site](http://www.majipoor.com/work.php?id=915):

> Harry is a typical teenager of his time, a bit on the nerdy side, insecure, and obsessed with sex. Suddenly he finds he can move things with his mind. It's the standard poltergeist situation, a frustrated kid channeling his energy into a little-used part of his brain. But can he control it? And what should he do with it? And would it make a good X-Files episode?